# PHP regex pattern not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing a very strange error with regex in php.
My Pattern is
`/\[B\]\[SIZE=3\](Trama|Recensione:|Curiosità|Trama:)\[\/SIZE\]\[\/B\](.*?)\[B\]\[SIZE=3\]/is`

And it works with "Trama", "Recensione:", and "Trama:", but not with "Curiosità" in my script. The strange thing is that if i type this pattern [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6Jf), it matches all correctly. What am I doing wrong?

My script:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `t`.`threadid`, `t`.`title`, `t`.`firstpostid`, `t`.`dateline`, `f`.`parentid` FROM {$db->tabelle['topic']} AS t, {$db->tabelle['forum']} AS f WHERE `f`.`forumid` = `t`.`forumid` AND `f`.`parentid` = ". (SEZIONE_RECENSIONI) ." AND `visible` = 1 ORDER BY `dateline` DESC LIMIT 10");
        while($thread = $db->fetch_array($query))
        {
            $post = $db->fetch_array($db->query("SELECT `pagetext`, `userid` FROM {$db->tabelle['post']} WHERE `postid` = {$thread['firstpostid']}"));

            $pattern = "/\[cover\](.*?)\[\/cover\]/is";
            preg_match($pattern, $post['pagetext'], $cover);

            $pattern = '/\[B\]\[SIZE=3\](Trama|Recensione:|Curiosità|Trama:)\[\/SIZE\]\[\/B\](.*?)\[B\]\[SIZE=3\]/isU';
            preg_match($pattern, $post['pagetext'], $trama);
            $content = remove_bbcode($parser->parse(truncate(utf8_encode($trama[2]), 350, '...', false, true)));
            $page .= "<li>
            <div class=\"recensione\" style=\"background: url(".$cover[1].") no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: 20% center; \">
                <p class=\"recensione_titolo\"><a href=\"?rec={$thread['threadid']}\">{$thread['title']}</a></p>
                <p class=\"recensione_content\">{$content} <a href=\"?rec={$thread['threadid']}\"><em>Continua a leggere</em></a></p>
            </div>
        </li>";
        }
```

Comment: Try adding `/U` flag to make it `/isU`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be an UTF8 problem, you can try to inform the regex engine that the target string must be read as an utff8 string. To do that you can add `(*UTF8)` at the begining or you can use the `u` modifier:

```
$pattern = '~(*UTF8)\[B]\[SIZE=3](Trama:?|Recensione:|Curiosità)\[/SIZE]\[/B](.*?)\[B]\[SIZE=3]~s';
```

or

```
$pattern = '~\[B]\[SIZE=3](Trama:?|Recensione:|Curiosità)\[/SIZE]\[/B](.*?)\[B]\[SIZE=3]~su';
```

Note: to avoid a lot of backslashes in your expression, to make it more readable:

- you can change the pattern delimiter, *(no need escape slashes)*
- the literal closing bracket doesn't need to be escaped.
- you can use \Q and \E to quote literal substring
- you can use the freespacing mode x

example:

```
$pattern = '~
    \Q[B][SIZE=3]\E
    (Trama:?|Recensione:|Curiosità)
    \Q[/SIZE][/B]\E   (.*?)  \Q[/SIZE][/B]\E ~xus';
```

Comment: Ok, it's a UTF8 problem, but if I use the `u` modifier it completely stops working.

Comment: @DavideR: try to determine what is the encoding of the original text, and convert it to utf8. (in particular, take a look at the default encoding in your code editor)

Comment: Ok, I thing I'm going to replace à, è, ì and any other special character with a, e, i and so on. Thank you for your suggestions.